# Freelancing in Germany: Selling concert tickets

Tags: germany, freelance

I am a freelance musician who just moved to Germany. I have been giving concerts and preparing invoices for the venues or organization companies.

Recently we made a door deal with a venue, and they asked me to handle the door operation, so I used eventbrite for selling the tickets to my audience. However then I read somewhere that I may need a trade licence for organizing my own concerts/sell goods.

I am a little bit confused since I did not sell any goods, I provided service (performance) for the ones who paid. I did not organize the concert per se. I got my fee, that I normally get from the venue, from the ticket sales.

But from another point of view I sold tickets -are they considered as goods?

I could not find any specific statement on this subject, the information I found was varied and confusing. How should I proceed on this matter? If using Eventbrite is a mistake, do you think there is another way to make people pay for the concert -should it be a donation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, anything which is not mentioned as exception in the `Einkommensteuergesetz` is a commercial activity (gewerbliche Tätigkeit).

Though `Freiberufler` can do commercial activities, there is just a very narrow range in DE (`Bagatellgrenze`). Exceeding it is a one way ticket: you‘ll do commercial activities forever from a tax point of view, with all duties (Handelsgesetzbuch, Pflicht zur Bilanz und doppelten Buchführung etc.)

I advise to contact a capable lawyer to avoid unwanted consequences.

I suggest to deny such activities.